# how to start firefox or other gui application on windows 7 remotely

Tags: windows-7, gui, remote

I am using ubuntu locally. Also I have another server running windows 7. I want to start firefox or notepad on windows 7 through the bash on ubuntu. And what I want is to let the firefox/notepad windows displayed on windows 7 like I started them locally on windows 7. I have SSH configured on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you in this is try using a VNC Server, they can be used on Windows or Linux systems and the clients are also available for linux.

I suggest looking up tightVNC
http://www.tightvnc.com/

Comment: Thank you for the introduction of this tools. It's nice. But actually I need start the application by some script on linux. I won't use the mouse or keyboard to start something. I would only run a script and let it start the GUI application on Windows 7 remotely